# Can you copy down an IMPORTXML function using an ArrayFormula?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get the below formula to copy down column D (in red) and have the same results as column E (in green)

```
={"Query in H1";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"",(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B3:B,IMPORTXML(A2:A,"//h1"))),"Yes","No"))))}
```

This formula collects the H1 (xpath) via the IMPORTXML function of the URL (column A) and checks to see if the keyword (column B) is included. If it is "Yes" if not "No"

See Google Sheet for reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iHkU-rNtNhoOKvW_CWY7WU5OLsMFVqEFNRZlx_R-7RY/edit#gid=1497887942

Comment: I think all the formula that return array will not be work with array formula but only when the formula return scalar value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your formula just needs a few modifications:**

- Remove the header text and modify the `SEARCH` parameters to `B2:B` such that the formula looks like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"",(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2:B,IMPORTXML(A2:A,"//h1"))),"Yes","No"))))
```

- Place the formula in the `D2` cell.

**After all the changes, this is how your sheet will look like:**

[image: modified formula]

**I have also taken the opportunity to create a copy of the sheet named *Answer* with all the modifications.**

Comment: Is this really working?  I know the formula will fill the column, but I believe that the IMPORTXML is always retrieving data for the URL in A2 in every instance, not cascading down through A3, A4, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we can not use ImportXML with ArrayFormula, the result after run formular will not correct. Even you see the result run down from the top to the last column, but the result will be wrong.

You can see an example in the screenshot below, with the same URL, the results in Column F and I are different from each other.

[image: Example]